# What is wrong with my import and export function?

Tags: javascript, import, module, export

I'm trying to import my function "update" and "draw" from my snake.js but nothing is shown on the console and no mistake is announced either...
is there something wrong with my code, can anyone help me? Thank you so much!

This is my game.js:

```
    import { update as updateSnake, draw as drawSnake, SNAKE_SPEED } from "/condition/snake.js"; //moves 2 times per second
    
    let lastRenderTime = 0
    
    
    function main(currentTime) {
        const secondsSinceLastRender = (currentTime - lastRenderTime) / 1000
        window.requestAnimationFrame(main)
        if (secondsSinceLastRender < 1 / SNAKE_SPEED) return
        lastRenderTime = currentTime
    
    
    
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(main)
    
    function update() {
        updateSnake()
    }
    
    function draw() {
        drawSnake()
    }

This is my snake.js:

    export const SNAKE_SPEED = 1
    
    export function update() {
        console.log('update snake')
    }
    
    export function draw() {
        console.log('draw snake')
```

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Snake</title>
    
</head>

<body>
    <div id="game-board"></div>

    <script src="game.js" type="module"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My directory:[image: directory]

Comment: `update` and `draw` do not seem to be called anywhere? (btw why is the program in the folder `JAVA APP`?)

Comment: i actually cut my folder out from JAVA APP folder, that's why

Comment: what do you mean by "update and draw do not seem to be called anywhere"

Comment: `game.js` does not contain `update()` or `draw()`?

Answer (score 0):

You import both functions and call them inside your `update()` and `draw()` functions, but the latter two aren't actually called. I suppose your `main()` function should represent a game loop where you update the game logic and render the game, which would make it look something like this:

```js
function main(currentTime) {
    const secondsSinceLastRender = (currentTime - lastRenderTime) / 1000
    window.requestAnimationFrame(main)
    if (secondsSinceLastRender < 1 / SNAKE_SPEED) return
    lastRenderTime = currentTime
    update();
    draw();
}
```

Maybe you actually did that but didn't include it in your example code, since there's quite a lot of whitespace at the end of your `main` function.

Your importing/exporting is just fine otherwise for ESM modules.